# How to click on an AngularJS link using Java Selenium?

Tags: java, angularjs, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium WebDriver with Java. I have done most things but I am stuck at one point, I have the following HTML code:

```
<a ng-href="#/studyenrollments/new" ng-show="canCreate" class="btn btn-primary edit-btn" href="#/studyenrollments/new">New Study Enrollment</a>
```

I've tried the following:

```
//new study enrollment
driver.findElement(By.linkText("New Study Enrollment")).click();    
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/a")).click();
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("document.querySelector(\"body > div.container.page.ng-scope > div.text-right.ng-scope > a\")");
```

I expect to click on the New Study Enrollment button and proceed to the next page to complete the registration process

Comment: are you sure there is no frame on page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Check if element it inside frame if yes - then  - select frame first -

   ```
   Select Frame    name or id of iframe
   ```

   then do the following -

   ```
   WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
   wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(".//a[@ng-show='canCreate']"))).click();
   ```
2. if there are no frames then  you can directly interact with the element -

   ```
   WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
   wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(".//a[@ng-show='canCreate']"))).click();
   ```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add explicit wait condition especially when working with pages with Angular JS elements

```
 WebElement newStudyEnrollment= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'New 
      Study Enrollment')]"));
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(newStudyEnrollment));
    newStudyEnrollment.click();
```

Answer (score -2):

Well, selenium web driver does not work with angular applications due to angular specific controls. You need to use protractor for automating angular and non-angular applications.

Comment: This is not true. Angular elements are HTML just like all elements. You might argue that it's easier to work with protractor and Angular but I would think that most people/companies aren't going to learn a brand new language just to make it a little easier they can use a language they are already familiar with.

Comment: Protractor literally uses Selenium WebDriver for its implementation.